# JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

As per [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), the `JSON.stringify()` method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified.

When a function is used as replacer parameter, it takes two parameters, the key and the value being stringified. The object in which the key was found is provided as the replacer's this parameter. Initially it gets called with an empty key representing the object being stringified, and it then gets called for each property on the object or array being stringified.

My question is what is the purpose of the first call of this function? The document does not state its behaviour/impact.

Comment: Can you cite some examples to clarify your question, please?

Comment: Funny thing how they carefully chose a convenient condition. It will just break if you decide to use anything else, like `key.indexOf('PUBLIC_') === 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [MSDN on JSON.stringify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836459(v=vs.84).aspx):

> The key for the root object is an empty string: "".

So this is just the root object.

It means the same as the explanation on MDN:

> Initially it gets called

This means it get's called for the root object, which is processed first

> with an empty key

That's an empty string.

> representing the object being stringified

Which again means the root object.

Note that an empty key can be used for an attribute in an object. So don't think that the empty string for the key makes it absolutely certain that the root object is being processed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but i still can not understand why we need this empty key passed to the replacer function. Is there any use case for this? Aren't the properties and values all we need to stringify an object?

Comment: The object you pass for stringification is not the value of any attribute, so there is no key. I'd prefer a framework that gives you the full path. For example `key = ".foo.bar[5].baz"; value = 42`. With the option to get the path as an array: `key = [ "foo", "bar", 5, "baz" ]` instead.

Then the root element would just have the empty key (`""` or `[]`).